# How do I clear the data in a plist created in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

I have been using a plist to store data in my app. I have been able to write and read from the plist with no problem. I created this plist in Xcode, adding the rows of numbers, dictionaries, and arrays myself. However, I would like to be able to reset the plist to the original state, and there must be an easier way to do this than writing a 0 or nil value to every entry in the plist. So what is the easiest way to reset the plist to its initial default state?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to delete the file using NSFileManager, like this:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:NULL];
```

Or if you don't want to do that, assuming the plist is a dictionary, just load the one from your application bundle and then overwrite the one in your documents, like this:

```
NSDictionary *originalPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundleFile];
[originalPlist writeToFile:documentsFile atomically:YES];
```

Which will overwrite the saved file with the original file.

Comment: Thank you that was what I was looking for. I guess I just needed someone to explain it to me directly.

Comment: Is it possible to delete  a single entry from a plist file?Basically I am storing dates in my plist and I want that, as the date stored the plist expires, that date/entry should be deleted from the plist and the plist should get refreshed.How can I do that?

Comment: You wouldn't delete it from the plist directly, you'd delete it from the dictionary by making a NSMutableDictionary using the mutableCopy method and then using the removeObjectForKey: method. Then just save the new dictionary over the top of the old plist.

Comment: The new syntax for removing the file is now: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:nil];

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mobile-watchlist.plist"];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to just rename your Plist. Thats the least work i think.